# exception when working with Java and metamodels java.lang.ClassCastException: javassist.bytecode.InterfaceMethodrefInfo cannot

Tags: java, sbt, metamodel

I am unable to run my Play java application last thing I did was to modify the meta models and some minor changes on the relationship of the entity classes, has anybody experience this issue before?

I do not really understand since the issue does not say anything about my code, any suggestion?

java.lang.ClassCastException: javassist.bytecode.InterfaceMethodrefInfo cannot be cast to javassist.bytecode.MethodrefInfo
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.getMethodrefType(ConstPool.java:452)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doInvokeMethod(Tracer.java:800)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doOpcode148_201(Tracer.java:597)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doOpcode(Tracer.java:81)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:187)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:164)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:108)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMap(MethodInfo.java:423)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMapIf6(MethodInfo.java:405)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:113)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.instrument(CtBehavior.java:712)
    at play.core.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer.rewriteAccess(PropertiesEnhancer.java:156)
    at play.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1$$anonfun$9.apply(PlayCommands.scala:99)
    at play.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1$$anonfun$9.apply(PlayCommands.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:264)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:263)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:105)
    at play.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1.apply(PlayCommands.scala:99)
    at play.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1.apply(PlayCommands.scala:76)
    at scala.Function8$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function8.scala:35)
    at scala.Function8$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function8.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

code:

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    public List substitute;

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
public List<Employee> employee;

public static volatile ListAttribute<User, Substitute> substitute;
public static volatile ListAttribute<User, Employee> employee;
```

The listAttribute used to be singularatrribute but I needed to change them after I change from a onetoone to a onetomany relationship

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: I added the snippets I changed @javaguy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen by the sbt-play-enhancer plugin using Javaassist version 3.18.0-GA.

Refer:https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3374

Add the 3.20 javassist upgrade to project/plugins.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.javassist" % "javassist" % "3.20.0-GA"
```